# How to send values in array format from android application to non web based server and retrive it?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a cloud computing based project. Where front end is android and back end java. On android, I need to collect 2 array lists Destinations and Activities.

I need to send these 2 array lists to java based server.

I too don't have much idea about it. How do I send the data to the back end server from android ?

Output as :

```
String[][] dest = new String[3][3];
    dest[0][0] = "Hyundai Car Center,Sector 63,Noida";
    dest[0][1] = "11:00";
    dest[0][2] = "2";
    dest[1][0] ="Sector 12,Noida";
    dest[1][1] = "09:00";
    dest[1][2] = "0.5";
    dest[2][0] ="GIP, sector 18,Noida";
    dest[2][1] = "14:00";
    dest[2][2] = "3.5";
String[][] activity = new String[2][2];
    activity[0][0] = "Buy Clothes";
    activity[0][1] = "0.5";
    activity[1][0] = "food";
    activity[1][1] = "1";
```

Comment: What is your question? Please point it out a little bit clearer. The question as it is is too broad.

Comment: Its like at front end I have to get input as (destination(like sector 51), deadline , time_duration) and (activity(eg: lunch ),time_duration)  from user in android app. Now these two sets of data I want in the form of array at my server side where I run a program to process these data. The server is not a web based as this

Comment: I still do not get what exactly you are having problems with. Do you want to know how to exchange those arrays between Server and Client? Or how to keep them up to date? Or how to get the array in a form to be sent on the line? What *is* your server if it isn't web based? Do you use TCP , UDP, pidgeons? Please edit your question and add these info.

Comment: I want how to exchange these arrays between client and server so that I cant access data on server side. From non web based I mean to say that I don't want Php, or mysql or apache server. I want like a ftp server .

Comment: So on the Server, there shall be human-readable files, that have as content what users put into those arrays on your Android Frontend, correct? The Android frontend shall retieve these files and send updated versions of them to the server, correct?

Comment: front end
Add dest
destinaion  timetoreach  Duration
sector 1       9:00         2
sector 2        11:00        1
Add activity 
activity         duration(hrs)
have lunch       2
go to temple      1
Now there is a button ,on which clicking these data is to be sent on server so that on server side we can have these values in a form of dest[][] and activity[][] array. I want how to send the data. All value what i have entered is by user in edit text. Now i want to retrieve this data at back end java program.

Comment: Ok, but how to send the data depends heavily on how your server works. For example you can establish a TCP connection and send the serialized array or an xml-serialization or a JSON-serialization. You could as well write a txt file and ftp it. There are many ways to meet your requirements. So *you* have to make some design decisions. Do you have already some server code?

Comment: No ,because I don't have idea about it. For now I had just assumed that I have values on server side in the form of array and working on the server side algorithm.

Comment: Basically @user2006536 wants us to help him write the code to send data thru json,sockets or any other means.

Answer (score 1):

create JSONArray and store in this your array

This is the format for JSON Array

```
["value1",
 "value2",
 "value3",
 "value4",
   ...
]
```

http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

Answer (score -1):

Create a static array in your java class and then add the values in your activity class. That will solve it right?

Comment: just as dest[i][j] = ""; and activity[i][j] = "" ; by this the value would be added into your class file

Comment: I can not reate a static array as size of dest array and activity array is not known in advance. It depends on what I will get from client side

Comment: the best one then is arraylist. create a static arraylist and then use it in activity as destinationarraylist.add(); and then if u really nead a array out there in java then get it from ary list to array.

Comment: front end
Add dest
destinaion  timetoreach  Duration
sector 1       9:00         2
sector 2        11:00        1
Add activity 
activity         duration(hrs)
have lunch       2
go to temple      1
Now there is a button ,on which clicking these data is to be sent on server so that on server side we can have these values in a form of dest[][] and activity[][] array. I want how to send the data. All value what i have entered is by user in edit text. Now i want to retrieve this data at back end java program.

Comment: ya u can do that all from arraylist. u can send the data to java class and store it in a server using any jsp or servlet. and prcess it frm java class.